# NodeJS + Mongo - how to get the contents of collection?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a simple NodeJS app with mongo. For connecting to mongo I use:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
Server = mongo.Server,
Db = mongo.Db,
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
db.open(function(err,db) {...};
```

So, I have database "docs", and I've created a collection called "companies". Now it has 4 objects (records) in it. I want to get the full contents of this collection as an array and show them line-by-line:

```
//get companies list
app.get('/companies',function(req,res){
db.collection("companies",function(err,collection){
    collection.find({},function(err, companies) {
        companies.forEach(function(err,company){
                console.log (company);
            }
        );
    });
});
});
```

However, Node returns me such error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'forEach'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `companies` parameter that's passed into your `find` callback is a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) object, not an array.  Call `toArray` on it to convert the query results to an array of objects, or `each` to process the results one at a time.

Comment: yeah, I got it, thanks! However, I'd like to ask one more question: every "company"-object has several fiels e.g. company_name. I'm trying to get it console.log (company.company_name);, but it doesnt work. It returns "Cannot read property 'company_name' of null" How could it be null if company is a valid part of Cursor?

Comment: When the `company` parameter passed into your `each` callback is null, that means you've hit the end of the cursor (there are no more results).

Comment: Not sure, I've understood you, oh. I'll try to read manual you provided, thanks. But how can I get the property company_name for current object "company"?

Comment: Just like you mentioned:  `company.company_name`

Comment: Oh, shame on me -  I've just noticed o_O It printed me 4 names, and on the fifth gave this error! It's because I have only 4 objects in this collection. But I still can't get it - if collection "companies" has only 4 objects, why after printing 4 object.names, node tries to get something else and gets an error? I supposed, it should print 4 compnay_names and exit function.

Comment: That's what I was talking about above.  The fifth time, the `company` parameter of the `each` callback is null, indicating the cursor has hit the end of the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12218/discussion-between-ilya-rusanen-and-johnnyhk)

Answer (score 3):

use .each on companies, instead of forEach

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use Mongoose tho. Huge time saver.

Comment: I've just wanted to ask you today: are there any differences between Mongoose and mongodb? Which is better?

Comment: @IlyaRusanen MongoDB is the NoSQL database. While Mongoose is an object modeling tool that lets you define schemas representing MongoDB documents (JSON Objects)